# htaccess rewrite subdirectory as root and also redirect if the subdirectory is accessed directly

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, root, subdirectory

### I have URLs like this

https://example.com/public
https://example.com/public/faq.php

### I want to rewrite it like this

https://example.com
https://example.com/faq.php

### Rule I am using is this

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteRule ^$ public/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

This rule works very well but it doesn't redirect if someone access "https://example.com/public/" or "https://example.com/public/faq.php"

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Please move your solution to its own answer, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

I have found a workaround for this. I have added below code to redirect if the public directory will be accessed directly.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /public [NC]
RewriteRule .* / [L,R]
```